# Mongodb multiple subdocument

Tags: mongodb, nosql, subdocument

I need a collection with structure like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ffc3e2df14de59d7347564d"),
    "name" : "MyName",
    "pays" : "de",
    "actif" : 1,
    "details" : {
        "pt" : {
            "title" : "MongoTime PT",
            "availability_message" : "In stock",
            "price" : 23,
            "stock" : 1,
            "delivery_location" : "Portugal",
            "price_shipping" : 0,
            "updated_date" : ISODate("2022-03-01T20:07:20.119Z"),
            "priority" : false,
            "missing" : 1,
        }, 
        "fr" : {
            "title" : "MongoTime FR",
            "availability_message" : "En stock",
            "price" : 33,
            "stock" : 1,
            "delivery_location" : "France",
            "price_shipping" : 0,
            "updated_date" : ISODate("2022-03-01T20:07:20.119Z"),
            "priority" : false,
            "missing" : 1,
        }
    }
}
```

How can i create an index for each subdocument in 'details' ?
Or maybe it's better to do an array ?

Doing a query like this is currently very long (1 hour). How can I do ?

```
query = {"details.pt.missing": {"$in": [0, 1, 2, 3]}, "pays": 'de'}
db.find(query, {"_id": false, "name": true}, sort=[("details.pt.updated_date", 1)], limit=300)
```

Answer (score 1):

An array type would be better, as there are advantages.

**(1)** You can include a **new field** which has values like `pt`, `fr`, `xy`, `ab`, etc. For example:

```
details: [
    { type: "pt", title : "MongoTime PT", missing: 1, other_fields: ... },
    { type: "fr", title : "MongoTime FR", missing: 1, other_fields: ... },
    { type: "xy", title : "MongoTime XY", missing: 2, other_fields: ... },
    // ...
]
```

Note the introduction of the new field `type` (this can be any name representing the field data).

**(2)** You can also **index on the array** sub-document fields, which can improve query performance. Array field indexes are referred as [Multikey Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/).

The index can be on a field used in a query filter. For example, `"details.missing"`. This key can also be part of a **Compound Index**. This can help a *query filter* like below:

```
{ pays: "de", "details.type": "pt", "details.missing": { $in: [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ] } }
```

NOTE: You can verify the usage of an index in a query by generating a **Query Plan**, applying the `explain` method on the `find`.

**(3)** Also, see [Embedded Document Pattern](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/#embedded-document-pattern) as explained in the **Model One-to-Many Relationships with Embedded Documents**.